# Conditional in reactJS for a specific bootstrap class depending on number of items rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS. ProductInfo is a card in my project that users can fill out with information. I want to set in my ReactJS code below a conditional in the Product const:

Where if only 2 ProductInfo cards are filled out, apply a col-md-6 to the className, so that the 2 cards are centered on the page.Other wise, use col-md-4 if there are more than 2 ProductInfo cards filled out. How would I go about doing this?

```
const ProductInfo = ({ title, blurb }) => (
    <div>
        {title && <h3 className="color-accent">{title}</h3>}
        {blurb &&
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: productBlurb}} />
        }
    </div>
);

const Product = (props) => (
//If only two ProductInfo cards are present, apply a boostrap class of col-md-6, otherwise apply the bootstrap class below
    <div className="hs-product col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4" >
        {props.productIconLink ?
            <a href={props.link} target="_blank">
                <ProductInfo {...props} />
            </a>
        :
            <ProductInfo {...props} />
        }
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you passing the ProductInfo data to Product through props. You could use a structure like this:

```
const ProductInfoData = [
 {
   title: 'title1',
   blurb: 'blurb1'
 },
 {
  title: 'title2',
  blurb: 'blurb2'
 },
 ...
]
```

Using this approach, you can then map through the array and render each ProductInfo. You'll even know how many ProductInfo components you are going to render, using `props.productInfoData.length`. You could do something like this:

```
const Product = (props) => {
    const className = 'hs-product col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ' + this.props.productInfoData.length == 2 ? 'col-md-6' : 'col-md-4';
    return (
        <div className={className}>
            {this.props.productInfoData.map((data) => {
                if (this.props.productIconLink) {
                    return (
                        <a href={props.link} target="_blank">
                            <ProductInfo {...data} />
                        </a>
                    )
                } else return <ProductInfo {...data} />;
             })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

This is how you would render `<Product />`:

```
const ProductInfoData = [
    {
        title: 'title1',
        blurb: 'blurb1'
    },
    ...
]

<Product productInfoData={ProductInfoData} />
```

Also, if I were you, I would avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. You usually don't have to use this and can rewrite your components so that they don't need this.